# How do I find the currently active editor with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, editor

I'm writing a hover event that needs to know which editor the user currently has their caret placed in.  How can I find the currently active editor from an event which is not actually triggered by that editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On focus of the editor, add up a class 'active' and on hover use $('.active'), this is where your caret is currently